# Groovy 1.5.x / Grails 1.0.x If-Else statement bug

Tags: grails, groovy, if-statement

I have this code in a Grails 1.0.4 Groovy console:

```
def devices = Device.getAll()

def found = devices.findAll {
    if(it?.localNumber && it?.areaCode){
        def pattern = ~".*${it.areaCode + it.localNumber}"
        def matches = "$msisdn" ==~ pattern
        println "$matches == msisdn: $msisdn ==~ pattern: $pattern"
        matches
    } else {
        false
    } // if-else
}

println "found: $found"
```

Which returns this:

```
discovering device: 048123456
true == msisdn: 048123456 ==~ pattern: .*48123456
true == msisdn: 048123456 ==~ pattern: .*48123456
true == msisdn: 048123456 ==~ pattern: .*48123456
false == msisdn: 048123456 ==~ pattern: .*48123457
found: []
```

Am I missing something or is it a bug ?

EDIT: I changed it like this:

```
def found = devices.findAll { 

    def matches = false
    if(it?.localNumber && it?.areaCode){
        def pattern = ~".*${it.areaCode + it.localNumber}"
        matches = "$msisdn" ==~ pattern
        println "$matches == msisdn: $msisdn ==~ pattern: $pattern"
    } else {
        matches = false
    } // if-else
    matches
}
```

and now it works! Shouln't the groovy if-else construct return a value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug/missing feature that was fixed in Groovy 1.6.x, so it'll work in Grails 1.1+. For Grails 1.0.x/Groovy 1.5.x you need to explicitly return a value from each if branch.